# macro to allocate space in memory

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64, masm

i need to make an assembly programmer to calculate **[pascal triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)** .
so that every line of pascal triangle stored in memory place separate from other line 
i want to make one but i have no idea how to do it in assembly using macro .

macro take an number and allocate that number of dword in memory

i did a try but i don't know if it is the correct way to do it

```
%macro Malloc 2
%2 : resd %1
%endmacro
```

i want to know 2 thing :

**first** i want the second arg ( **%2** ) to have a string name automatically for example

first line name :"line1" and next line to be "line2" "line3"  ...  and so on so i don't need to put my self  ?

**second** thing is this is a good idea to use macro in this case ?

Comment: Since you're calling it "malloc", I'm going to say no, you're not doing it correctly.  This will not be a dynamic allocation, this will be a static allocation in your code.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer hhhh what a coincidence i was thinking about taking sec760 this days hhhh

Comment: Awesome.  If you do and I'm around, stop in and say hi

Comment: A better label name would probably be `row1`, `row2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For NASM**: What you want here is [the `%+` operator](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.1.4) to concatenate things (after expanding single-line `%assign` macros), inside [a `%rep` block](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.5).

```
section .bss

%assign i 1
%rep    64
    line %+ i:  resd  i
%assign i i+1
%endrep
```

This assembles identically to

```
section .bss
line1:    resd 1     # reserve space for 1 DWORD
line2:    resd 2     # reserve space for 2 DWORDs
line3:    resd 3     # reserve space for 3 DWORDs
...
```

---

Testing:

```
$ nasm -felf64  pascal-triangle-macro.asm
$ nm -n pascal-triangle-macro.o        # sort by numeric address, not lexicographic

0000000000000000 b line1
0000000000000004 b line2
000000000000000c b line3
0000000000000018 b line4
0000000000000028 b line5
000000000000003c b line6
0000000000000054 b line7
0000000000000070 b line8
0000000000000090 b line9
00000000000000b4 b line10
00000000000000dc b line11
0000000000000108 b line12
...
```

As expected, the label addresses are in a geometric progression.  (Starting from 0 because this is an object file, not a linked executable).

Comment: Just a nitpick: the series of addresses is not a geometric progression (e.g. 24:12 != 12:4), it is more of a scaled triangular progression. The differences form an arithmetic progression with common difference 4 though.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I think I meant that it grows approximately geometrically, because `n*(n+1)` is O(n^2).